# Built in chroot jail RHEL 5 returns No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, rhel5, chroot

I need to create a chroot jail on my RHEL5 production server to allow a specific user to work with the less right possible, but with GIT.

Here is my system configuration :

- RHEL 5 : Release 5.10
- OpenSSH : OpenSSH_6.4p1, OpenSSL
    0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

I've created, for testing, a folder **/chroot** with a subfolder **toto** where I want to chroot my user.

```
# ls -la /chroot
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 11 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 31 root root 4096 Nov 12 13:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Nov 11 15:22 toto

# ls -la /chroot/toto
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 11 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 11 15:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 11 15:22 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 11 15:22 lib
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 11 15:22 usr
```

I've created a chroot group named **chroot_www** and added my user **toto** to it.

I've edited **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** and added the necessary lines at the end.

```
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group chroot_www
#       ForceCommand internal-sftp
        ChrootDirectory /chroot/toto
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

But when I want to connect with ssh I get this error :

```
ssh toto@********
toto@********'s password: 
Last login: Thu Nov 14 13:22:35 2013 from ********
Could not chdir to home directory /chroot/toto: No such file or directory
Connection to ******** closed.
```

but the directory exists, and the rights are good.

And it's strange for two reason :

- I've got the same configuration on a RHEL6 server and it's working.
- I can connect with SFTP and I'm chroot jailed in the right folder, but I can't with SSH.

So I'm really interested if you got experience with chroot jail or problem like this one...